# How to make RabbitMQ API calls with vhost "/"?

Tags: rabbitmq, urlencode

The following API call to RabbitMQ:

```
http -a USER:PASS localhost:15001/api/queues/
```

Returns a list of queues:

```
[
    {
         ...
         "messages_unacknowledged_ram": 0,
         "name": "foo_queue",
         "node": "rabbit@queue-monster-01",
         "policy": "",
         "state": "running",
         "vhost": "/"
     },
     ...
]
```

Note that the `vhost` parameter is `/`.

**How do I use a `/` `vhost` for the [`/api/queues/vhost/name`](http://hg.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmq-management/raw-file/3646dee55e02/priv/www-api/help.html) call, which returns the details for a specific queue?**

I have tried:

- `localhost:15001/api/queues/\//foo_queue`
- `localhost:15001/api/queues///foo_queue`

But both failed with `404 Object Not Found`:

[image]

Answer (score 34, accepted):

[URL Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) did the trick. The URL should be:

```
localhost:15001/api/queues/%2F/foo_queue
                           ⬆⬆⬆
```

For the record, I think that REST resources should not be named `/`, especially not by default.

Comment: I change as per your answer. Still I have the same message in return `[error] => Object Not Found
    [reason] => "Not Found"
`

Answer (score -1):

To answer Avishake's issue with the original answer (Not Found).

The reason you got Not Found is because you should replace **%2F** with **base**. Unicode encoding is the wrong approach.

Note that the vhost parameter is / when you query for all queues.

```
    [
    {
         ...
         "messages_unacknowledged_ram": 0,
         "name": "q.somequeue",
         "node": "rabbit@queue-monster-01",
         "policy": "",
         "state": "running",
         "vhost": "/"
     },
     ...
    ]
```

If you replace the / with %2F (the unicode approach) you will get not found. By replacing / with base (the non-unicode approach) you will get a response that is successful.

**Incorrect**: http://RabbitMQHost:port/api/queues/%2F/q.somequeue

**Correct** http://RabbitMQHost:port/api/queues/base/q.somequeue